# $T:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map and $v_1...v_n$ be basis for $V$. Prove $\{T(v_1)...(T(v_n\}$ is basis for range(T). Is this proof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

So the theorem is

> Let $T : V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. Prove that if $B = \{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is a basis for the domain $V$ then $S = \{T(v_1), T(v_2), \cdots , T(v_n\}$ is a basis for the range $T$.

The proof I came across: (Note that in the proof we assume that we already know $T(v_1),\cdots, T(v_n)$ span $range(T)$

[image]

When proving linear independence of $S$, he only considers the case

$$T(O) = O$$

What about the case where $b \in V$ and $b ≠ O$, but

$$T(b) = O$$?

Clearly, we can rewrite $b$ as the linear combination of vectors in $B$

$$b = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_iv_i$$

And after substituting and rearranging, we have following

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_1T(v_1) = O$$

where not all scalars $c$ are zero.

For the proposition to be correct, this case must be impossible. But why is so?

So in summary:

**Question 1**

Is the proof above correct? If it is so, why he didn't consider the case where $b \in V$, $b ≠ O$ but $T(b) = O$?

**Question 2**

Is there an alternative way to prove the theorem? (Preferably I would like see the proof that would start like : "Suppose $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ form a basis. Consider linear combiation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_iT(v_i) = O$. Then we have......")

Comment: The "theorem" is false. Consider $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(a,b)=a$. Then $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $\{T(1,0),T(0,1)\}=\{1,0\}$ is not even linearly independent, and hence not a basis for $\text{range}(T)$.  And you're right, the "proof" is actually nonsense.  Where did you find it?

Comment: @BenW  I found the "theorem" above in the book "Linear Algebra: Step by Step". The author is Kuldeep Singh. (Chapter 5, section 5.2, exercise 10). It is quite surprising to see incorrect theorems here though, since the publisher is Oxford press....

Comment: Yeah that is surprising.  I don't know what to say though.  I would have said it's possible he just made a minor mistake in leaving out "a subset of" or something.  But looking at his proof, it's just utter nonsense.  Whoever wrote that is not ready to be teaching you linear algebra.

Comment: Well it's not the end of the world or anything.  I mean, I'm sure most of it's correct.  But if he made an error of that magnitude, I doubt it's the only one in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "theorem" is false, and the "proof" is nonsense for exactly the reason you pointed out.

However, there is an actual (true) theorem which is reminiscent.

**Theorem.**  Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear map between vector spaces $V$ and $W$.  Then the following are equivalent.

**(i)**  For any $\mathcal{B}\subseteq V$, we have that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $V$ if and only if $T(\mathcal{B})$ is a basis for $T(V)$.

**(ii)**  $T$ is injective.

**(iii)**  $\mathcal{N}(T)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

That "proof" is blatantly false. Your worries are 100% justified. In fact, we can show that the conclusion of that theorem is true if and only if there is no $0\neq b\in V$ with $T(b)=0$, which happens if and only if $T$ is injective.

The reason why the "proof" doesn't work is because the author does not consider an arbitrary linear combination (to show linear independence, one can take a linear combination that sums to $0$ and has to show it is trivial), but only considers the linear combination where all the coefficients are already $0$. The "proof" of linear independence is merely an incoherent way of restating that $T(0)=0$.

To immediately see that the conclusion of the "theorem" is false, consider the linear map $T\colon V\rightarrow W,\,v\mapsto0$; if $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, then $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_n)\}=\{0\}$ is not a basis for $\mathrm{im}(T)=\{0\}$ (the zero vector is not linearly independent). Whatever the text you are reading is, I recommend being very wary of it in the forthcoming considering it has a mistake of this caliber.